# I got an epic chest before the legendary chest what does that mean for me?

Tags: clash-royale

Does this mess up my cycle? Or do I still have a chance of getting a legendary chest.

Answer (score 1):

It means  you got lucky. Apparently our of cycle chests don't mess up the cycle, so you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty well known that for the first cycle, you get legendary and epic chests together. You'll still get 10 epics and a legendary.

Answer (score 0):

**I really think that the Legendary and Epic Chests coming toghether was just a one-time thing.** So, I don't really think you would earn another Chest group.