# I just got an epic chest. Will i get a legendary chest next battle and/or sometime soon

Tags: clash-royale

I just got my first epic chest from battle and I am in arena 7. Although I did get my epic chest, I didn't get a legendary chest before the epic, and I have never obtained the legendary chest from battle. Since I just got the epic chest, will I get a legendary chest in the next battle and/or sometime soon? I have also been waiting for a long time to get the legendary chest.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/292384/171549 this might answer you!

Comment: It is not necessary but you can track your chest cycle at statsroyale.com

Answer (score 1):

> **How do the Chests drop? It’s based on the Clash Royale Chest Cycle!**
>
> Basically there is a chest order (or chest cycle) in game. Every Chest that you get after the Battles is based on this list. When this cycle goes through, it will restart again.
>   By digging the game files, Asdamp (Pearce) has found this chest order list.
>
> Small note:
>
> You will always get 6 Wooden Chests at first, during the Training Camp.
>   This is the latest pattern, updated on 30th December 2016.
>
> **What about the Legendary Chest?**
>
> Shared by iMix-
>
> You have the chance to get this chest once you hit 2000 trophies.
>   Below Arena 9, you are guaranteed a Legendary Chest in every 2 cycles (yes, the circle above).
>
> In Arena 9, you are guaranteed a Legendary Ches in every chest cycle.
>   This chest randomly replaces a chest in the Clash Royale Chest Cycle.
>
> If you bounce between Arenas, your Legendary chest drop rate is still one per 2 cycles. You need to stay in Arena 9 during the entire cycle to get one chest every cycle.

This information was from:
http://clashroyalearena.com/tips/how-does-the-chest-drop

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. I guess Supercell only gave those 2 Chests together just for a limited time. **So no, you cannot predict whether or not you will get a Legendary Chest soon.**

Answer (score 0):

The next chest you will get will be the legendary chest, the cycle has the order(for the rare chests) legendary, supermagical, epic.

Answer (score -1):

Legendary and Epic chest odds are independent of one another. You are not guaranteed a legendary chest. There is no way of telling when your legendary chest will drop, but if you are near the end of the cycle, you may be getting one soon.

[Orange Juice Gaming has an excellent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6A4711tQzM) on chest odds.